# Serialization/Deserialization in Java of HashMap<Int,Object> using Gson

Tags: java, json, debugging, gson, deserialization

I am trying to use google's Gson library to serialize and de-serialize a HashMap in Java. I'd like to serialize the hashmap shown here, save it to a file, and then read from a file at a later stage and deserialize it.

The HashMap is as follows

```
public static HashMap<Integer,HashMap <Integer, Type5Val>> type5Model = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Type5Val>>();
```

The Deserialization Logic for deserialization class, and the object class I have implemented so far based on examples found on the web. is:

```
public class Type5Val implements Serializable,JsonDeserializer<Type5Val>{

    public int modelLogLines;
    public int modelTime;       

    @Override
    public Type5Val deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

        System.out.println("Print JSON Object" + jsonObject.getAsString());

        final int t_modelLogLines = jsonObject.get("modelLogLines").getAsInt();
        final int t_modelTime = jsonObject.get("modelTime").getAsInt();

        //Populating
        Type5Val val = new Type5Val();
        val.modelLogLines = t_modelLogLines;
        val.modelTime = t_modelTime;

        return val;
    }
}
```

The following is a code for serializing, and deserializing which is called in the test function. The test function serializes an Object of HashMap above, creates a string, and then tries to deserialize it. The deserialization is currently failing:

```
//serialization code
public static String dump(){

    // Configure Gson
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Type5Val.class, new Type5Val());

    Gson g = gsonBuilder.create();
    String json = g.toJson(type5Model);
    return json;
}

//deserialization code
public static HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer,Type5Val>> undump(String json){

    // Configure Gson
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Type5Val.class, new Type5Val());

    Gson g = gsonBuilder.create();
    HashMap<Integer,HashMap <Integer, Type5Val>> newModel =  g.fromJson(json, type5Model.getClass());
    return newModel;
}

public static void printMap(HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,Type5Val>> modelInput){

    Iterator<HashMap<Integer, Type5Val>> it = modelInput.values().iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        HashMap<Integer,Type5Val> temp = it.next();
        Iterator<Type5Val> it2 = temp.values().iterator();

        while(it2.hasNext()){
            Type5Val temp2 = it2.next();
            System.out.println("Time: " + temp2.modelTime + " Lines: " + temp2.modelLogLines);
            System.out.println(" Queue Size " + temp2.q.size() + "\n");
        }
    }
}

public static void testcase(){

    System.out.println("Printing Initial Map");
    printMap(type5Model);

    //serialization
    String s = dump();
    System.out.println(s);

    //deserialization
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer,Type5Val>> newModel = undump(s);

    System.out.println("Printing Map After Serialization/Deserialization");
    printMap(newModel);

}
```

The follwing is the exception I get, I have tagged the JSON output after the serialization (which works). The exception is in the deserialization.

```
Printing Initial Map
Time: 0 Lines: 39600000
 Queue Size 0

Time: 0 Lines: 46800000
 Queue Size 0

//Json output after serialization
{"1":{"1":{"modelLogLines":39600000,"modelTime":0,"q":[]},"2":{"modelLogLines":46800000,"modelTime":0,"q":[]}}}
Printing Map After Serialization/Deserialization
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
        at violationChecker.type5Convert.printMap(type5Convert.java:207)
        at violationChecker.type5Convert.testcase(type5Convert.java:259)
        at violationChecker.type5Convert.main(type5Convert.java:294)
        ... 6 more
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone give further tips in Deserialization in Gson?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." You aren't describing the specific problem, you are just giving a test that fails.

Comment: I think the very top of the question mentions the functionality I am seeking.. how to serialize/deserialize a HashMap using Gson. What kind of specifics would be required apart from that for desired behavior? I'd like to serialize the Java HashMap above, save it to a file, and then deserialize the string as well

Comment: That is not a problem, it is a description of what you are trying to do. "The test-for this fails however:" How does it fail? What exception occurs?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have added the exception output, a sample json output and where it fails.

Comment: The exception is occurring in your `printMap` method. Please give the code for that.

Comment: added the printMap function.

Comment: I faced similar issue for HashMap. When you have complex HashMap, GSON returns LinkedTreeMap default. This is causing problem. If you are open to other open source solutions, then I would suggest Jackson. It just works. Try it.

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
HashMap<Integer,HashMap <Integer, Type5Val>> newModel =  g.fromJson(json, type5Model.getClass());
```

You are telling Gson to deserialize the `String` as a `HashMap`. Just a `HashMap`, not a `HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Type5Val>>`, because all that information about the generic type parameters is erased at runtime, and what you're passing it is the runtime known type of `type5Model`. That forces Gson to guess about the types that are supposed to be in your `HashMap` as its keys and values, and it's making `LinkedTreeMap` instead of `HashMap` for the inner maps in your values.

To give Gson the full type, including generic type parameters, you will have to use a [`TypeToken`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html). To create the appropriate `TypeToken`, do this:

```
new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Integer, Type5Val>>>(){}.getType()
```

Pass the result of that to the `fromJson` call in place of `type5Model.getClass()`, and you should get what you were expecting. It might be more readable to create the `TypeToken` on one line, store it in a temp variable, and pass the variable instead of cramming it all onto one line.

On another note, the fact that you're using `HashMap` instead of `Map` everywhere is prone to bugs. Almost certainly most of your code only really cares about the behavior specified by `Map`, and in that case should be written in terms of `Map` only. If it were, Gson's choice of what type of `Map` to use would work just fine and this error would never have happened.

You'd still get another error somewhere else without the `TypeToken`, though, because Gson would never guess without being told that some of the objects are supposed to be of the `Type5Val` class.